# Pass value from shell to main class without static methods

Tags: java, shell, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

everyone.

I am writing a code which consists in two screens: The main screen (composite), this screen contains all important data of a client. The second screen is a shell that shows a list of all registered clients on my DB. Let's assume I have opened the second screen to search for a client. I found it and doubleclicked on it. As of now, I am using static methods to send the selected values from this shell to my main class. But since I am using eclipse rap, a static method just won't be possible, otherwise, all current users would share the same data, correct?
Is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure about eclipse-rap. but you just need to manage per session object. without knowing eclipse-rap I can think of Map of userId to SessionData data structure. I am sure there will be better deciplined framework around it for your project setup

Comment: Use instance methods instead. Instantiate the class for each `User` or `Session`. This all comes down to the object model. Coding without analysis is like driving without directions. Does the analysis indicate one object for everything in the system? Does each session share its data or does it have its own? A good object model tends to induce good code.